# Thymeleaf break loop if my condition is satisfied

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is it possible to stop in thymeleaf `th:each`? My problem is the title will show multiple times... one title for every entry in the database.

[image]

html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div th:each="movie : ${movies}" class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div th:each="movieUser : ${movieUserWatched}">
            <h4 th:if="${movie.id} == ${movieUser.id}">
              <i style="float: left; color: green; margin-right: 2%;"
                 class="fa fa-check-circle"> </i>
              <span class="info-box-number" th:text="${movie.title}">MovieName</span>
            </h4>
            <h4 th:unless="${movie.id} == ${movieUser.id}">
              <span class="info-box-number" th:text="${movie.title}">MovieName</span>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img style="margin-left: -16%; margin-bottom: -8%; opacity: 1; margin-top: -8%;"
                 data-sizes="auto" th:alt="${movie.title}" th:src="@{${movie.poster_path}}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">Genre Infos</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <a href="#" th:href="@{'/movie/' + ${movie.id} }"
             class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code for the 2 Lists:

```
@RequestMapping( value = ( "/movies" ) )
public String Movie( Model model ) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User currentUser = userDao.findOneByUsername( auth.getName() );

    Iterable<Movie> movie = movieDao.findAll();

    List<UserMovie> UserWatched = currentUser.getUserMovies();

    List<Movie> movieUserWatched = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    for (UserMovie u: UserWatched) {
        movieUserWatched.add( u.getMovie() );
    }

    model.addAttribute( "movies", movie );
    model.addAttribute( "movieUserWatched", movieUserWatched );

    return "home/movies";
}
```

The movie data table

[image]

The watched movie data table

[image]

Hope you can help me! :)

Comment: You might be better off filtering the duplicates on the server-side.  A simple solution would be to use a `Set` or even better, update your query to return distinct results.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please don't post or link to screenshots of text (or text data). Copy/paste the text itself into the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to simplify the if statement from `th:if="${movie.id} == ${movieUser.id}"` to `th:if="${movie.id == movieUser.id}"` cause it gives you a better vision.

Then try below code, it would work properly

```
<div th:each="movie : ${movies}" class="col-md-6">
    <h4 th:if="${#lists.contains(movieUserWatched, movie)}">
        <i ... class="fa fa-check-circle"> </i>
        <span ... th:text="${movie.title}">MovieName</span>
    </h4>
    <h4 th:unless="${#lists.contains(movieUserWatched, movie)}">
        <span ... th:text="${movie.title}">MovieName</span>
    </h4>
</div>
```